# What happens if I send a XRP transaction to a blank TAG when I was supposed to send to a specifc TAG?

Tags: hash, ripple

I sent XRP to a blank TAG while I was supposed to send to the éxchange's TAG. The address is the one from the exchange but the TAG was left blank. The exchange says that they can't recover the money.

What happened to the money? Is it theoretically possible for the exchange to recover it? As I understood, a blank tag but rigth address will send the money to the exchange but not in the account of anyone.

Answer (score 1):

Most exchanges configure their accounts so that attempts to transfer funds to them without a destination tag will fail. If this is the case, then the transaction would have failed and the XRP would still be in the sending account. Otherwise, the XRP was received by the exchange but they have no easy way to know what account to credit.

Answer (score -1):

I suppose TAG is neccessary for identify user. Person will get XRP from you, when you specify his tag at transaction details. At situation when you will leave blank TAG field, then your money will be transfered to general account or will be lost. It is impossible to (easy) prove you are owner of account from which this transfer was been send, so anyone will not recover your money.